# Project Euler 29, "pen and paper" solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, arithmetic

the problem is the following:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=29

I've been trying to find a "pen and paper" solution for this problem. I thought I had one but it turned out to be wrong and I can't find the mistake. My approach is the following:

I've tried to count duplicates. If $a$ is a perfect power (less or equal to 100), the sequence $a^2,...,a^{100}$ will contain duplicates. Let's write it when $a$ is a power of "2".

If $a=4$ the sequence is:

$$4^2,...4^{50},...4^{100}$$

but the first $49$ numbers in this sequence were already counted when $a=2$ because $4^2=(2^{2})^{2},...4^{50}=(2^{2})^{50}$.

Similarly, when $a=2^3$ you can find $32$ duplicates: from $8^2$ to $8^{33}$, both included.  For $a=2^4$ you get $24$ duplicates, for $a=32$ you get $19$ and for $a=64$, you get $15$.

Actually, if $a=x^n$, the integer division of $100/n$ gives you the number of duplicates $+ 1$ (because the sequence starts at $2$).

If you count duplicates like that for the powers of $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ and $10$ (it gets easier and easier, you only have to check 1 power of each from 5 on) you get 619 duplicates. Finally my answer is $99^2-619=9182$. (subtract the duplicates form the length of the sequence with duplicates).

Please can someone help me find the mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Explicitly, you forgot that $4^{52}=16^{26}$, as well as many other duplicates.

Comment: $4^{51} = 8^{34}$ and so on, you have more duplicates for base $8$.